# I don't get the output in the form I expect

Tags: c++, output, numerical-methods

In this program you input coordinates of points and their velocity components. It should give in output the point that is closest to (0,0,0), and its distance from (0,0,0). This is the main body of the program:

```
#include "tacka4.h"
#include "vektor1.h"
#include "brzina.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  cout << "Broj tacaka? "; int n; cin >> n;
  Tacka** tacke = new Tacka* [n];
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)  {
     cout << "Koordinate tjemena " << i << "? ";
     double x, y, z; cin >> x >> y >> z;
     cout << "Komponente brzine? ";
     double vx, vy, vz; cin >> vx >> vy >> vz;
     tacke[i] = new Tacka (Vektor (x, y, z), Brzina (vx, vy, vz));
     }

     cout << "\nBroj koraka? "; int k; cin >> k;
     cout << "Trajanje koraka? "; double dt; cin >> dt;
     const Tacka org;
     cout << "ORG  " << org << "\n\n";

     for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<n; tacke[j++]->proteklo(dt));
         double min = rastojanje (org, *tacke[0]); int m=0;
         for (int j=1; j<n; j++) {
            double d = rastojanje (org, *tacke[j]);
            if (d<min) { min = d; m = j; }
         }
         cout << i << ' ' << *tacke[m] << ' ' << min << endl;
         }

         return 0;
 }
```

I actually get something like this, for example:

```
T3102720.3112960.3112960.310528 0.519615
```

I need this result in the form:

```
T3 (0.3, 0.3, 0.3) 0.519615
```

This is the class tacka4.h

```
#ifndef _tacka4_h_
#define _tacka4_h_

#include "pokretan.h"
#include "vektor1.h"
#include "brzina.h"

class Tacka: public Pokretan {
  static int ukId;
  const int id;
  Vektor r;
  Brzina v;
public:
 Tacka (const Vektor& rr=Vektor (),
         const Brzina& vv=Brzina () )
     : r (rr), v (vv), id (++ukId) {}
  Tacka (const Tacka& T)
     : r (T.r), v (T.v), id(++ukId) {}
  Tacka& operator= (const Tacka& T)
     { r = T.r; v = T.v; return *this; }
  Pokretan& proteklo (double dt)
     { r = r + v * dt; return *this; }
  Vektor R () const {return r; }
  friend double rastojanje (const Tacka& T1, const Tacka& T2)
     {return + (T1.r + T2.r * -1);}
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& d, const Tacka& T)
     {return d << 'T' << T.id << T.r; }
};
#endif
```

Comment: Use `setprecision` to set the number of digits after the decimal point. You're also not printing the parentheses, why do you expect them?

Comment: I don't see anything that prints `T` at the beginning. Where is that coming from?

Comment: I guess the `Tacka` class has a `<<` method, but you haven't posted it. That seems to be where the numbers in parentheses should be printed.

Comment: Because I am complete newbie, but in spite of that need to get this work. This is not actually the program I wrote, to be sincere.

Comment: I added the class tacka4.h, but I still can't realize where to put brackets.

Comment: Put the brackets around `T.r` in the `operator<<` method.

Comment: Like this?
       {return d << 'T' << T.id << '(' << T.r<<  ')' ; }

Comment: Yeah. You'll also need to use `setprecision` so it doesn't display all those decimal digits.

Comment: Are you sure that I get this due to many decimal digits? I don't have commas, and a set of numbers is continuously repeated, as here: http://imgur.com/JSsAFVN

Comment: The commas will have to be done by the `operator<<` method in `Vektor`.